# Matplotlib colorbar not shrinking

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I am using custom colorbar in my plot with following code

```py
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.gridspec import GridSpec

cmap = matplotlib.cm.get_cmap("hot")
norm = matplotlib.colors.Normalize(vmin=0, vmax=10)
sm = plt.cm.ScalarMappable(cmap=cmap, norm=norm)
fig = plt.figure()
gs = GridSpec(10, 10, figure=fig)
ax = fig.add_subplot(gs[1:, :])
colorbar_ax = fig.add_subplot(gs[0, :])
plt.colorbar(cax=colorbar_ax, mappable=sm, orientation="horizontal",
                 shrink=0.5)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

This gives me following output,
[image]

For some other aspects of my other code, I HAVE to use `gridspec`. How can I shrink the colorbar by half (or any other fraction)? `shrink=0.5` or `fraction=0.5` are not working.

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation for `colorbar`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.colorbar.html):

> The shrink kwarg provides a simple way to scale the colorbar with
>   respect to the axes. Note that if cax is specified, it determines the
>   size of the colorbar and shrink and aspect kwargs are ignored.

So you can't use `shrink` if you are using gridspec.

Of course, `gridspec` is designed to make sizing of subplot axes easy, so we can use that to define the colorbar axes size. Since you already have a 10x10 grid defined by gridspec, we could just use the middle portion in the x-direction; For example, you could change to something like this to shorten your colorbar:

```
colorbar_ax = fig.add_subplot(gs[0, 3:7])
```

Comment: I had thought about it but problem with this approach is limitation in adjusting size. For example, if I want to shrink it to 0.35, how will I adjust `GridSpec`?

Comment: you can modify the `GridSpec` instance to give you anything you want. For example, you could make it `gs = GridSpec(10, 100, figure=fig)`, then you can make it 35% of the width using `colorbar_ax = fig.add_subplot(gs[0, 33:68])` or something like that.

Comment: That make sense. +1. I can try it. I was hoping for some way to scale the colorbar axis.